# Unit testing vue routing with b-button "to"

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

I have a component that contains a b-button component from Vue Bootstrap. In my the unit test, I want to check that when I click that button within the component, I get routed to the url I specified in the "to" prop I'm passing to b-button.

My problem is the routing is not being triggered in my unit test. Or b-button / router-link within it aren't using the my router instance.

How can I test this? Do I even need to? I've simplified my examples - I know that the "to" functionality is covered by b-button's own unit tests, but I wanted to test that I'm passing the correct url to it.

Demo component

```
<template>
    <b-card
        header="Button demo"
    >
        <b-button
            class="test"
            v-bind:to="toPath"
        >Test</b-button>
    </b-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    name: 'ButtonDemo',

    data(){
        return {
            toPath: '/expected/path'
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Unit test

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import ButtonDemo from '@/path/to/ButtonDemo'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter()

localVue.use(BootstrapVue)

describe('List', () => {

    let $wrapper

    test('Clicking "new" takes you to the create flow', async () => {

        $wrapper = mount(ButtonDemo, { localVue, router })

        $wrapper.find('.test').trigger('click')

        expect($wrapper.vm.$route.path).toBe('/expected/path')

    })

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test that the `to` prop set on `b-button` is the expected value.

```
let button = $wrapper.find('.test')
expect(button.props('to')).toBe('/expected/path')
```

As you said, tests for routing to a given path should already be covered by unit tests of `b-button` component.

Side Note: Please consider using `shallowMount` instead of `mount` in your unit tests.

Comment: And since `<b-button>` renders a `<router-link>` (which in turn renders a `<a>`), you can check for the `href` attribute to see that it has a value that corresponds to your expected route's path.

Comment: That makes sense - thank you! "mount" is a leftover from the full code that I forgot to change.

Comment: @Iainure  Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the `tick` icon so that it helps other people in the community.

Comment: @AnkitKante - will do. But I'll accept an answer in a few days to give time for any further replies